# UIReferenceLibraryViewController with Japanese-English dictionary causes app to freeze for certain words

Tags: ios, swift

On an iPhone X running iOS 11.4.1, built with Xcode 9.4.1, the following code causes the app to become completely unresponsive:

```
let dictionaryVC = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "mundane")
self.present(dictionaryVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This occurs when the Japanese-English dictionary is installed.

If the Japanese-English dictionary is the only dictionary installed, the initial definition screen is shown, but pressing the back 'Dictionary' button on that screen causes the app to become unresponsive.

If the Japanese-English dictionary plus one or more other dictionaries are installed, the definition screen is not shown at all, and the app becomes unresponsive.

I have created a project to illustrate the problem: https://github.com/Paludis/A-Mundane-Problem

Unless I'm missing something this seems to be a bug on Apple's end?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in iOS 12.

Comment: I have the same problem on iOS 15.5.

But "mundane" no longer causes this problem. In my environment, the app freezes when I open "peek" and "hassle".